# Gerenciamento de clientes com OAuth

Tags: oauth

Boa noite pessoal
Estou começando a estudar OAauth, e fazendo alguns testes utilizando o twitter e google. Porém me surgiu as seguintes dúvidas para o determinado cenário, por exemplo:

Após desenvolver uma API Rest, onde eu tenha em média 500 clientes acessando essa API:

- Utilizando serviços do twitter ou google. Tem a possibilidade de gerar um token de acesso diferente para cada um dos clientes?
- Isso tem como ser feito de maneira automática, ou teria que ser feito manualmente para cada cliente?
- Ou o ideal seria ter um token geral para todos os 500 clientes?